# how generate chart from Views Aggretation Plus

Tags: views, charts

I created a table from webform submission data (group and compress) using [Views Aggregator Plus](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_aggregator)

[image]

I would like to generate a pie chart from this table (industry as the label and turnover as the values).

Any hints to generate the pie chart would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I can do that,

(a) Exclude the Company field
(b) In the VAP setting, disable the summary sum in the footer
(b) Then use [highcharttable](https://www.drupal.org/project/highcharttable) module to create the pie chart.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts)  module

> Transform Data into Information. Charts are a very good way to visualize a lot of data in a way that can be quickly digested.

It has a Views integration that Display the Views results as charts.

There are similar modules check [Check Views Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_charts) , [Charts and Graphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts_graphs)

Comment: @Krisna Mohan. I got the charting tools and I tried that. The problem is I cannot get the aggregated  values in industry field, always: Food Food Clothing IT IT

Comment: I still don't have the answer to do that. It is related to the project discussion https://www.drupal.org/node/2360781